# Entry To, Entry Into

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference, usage

A preposition question:

> The United States earned ***entry to*** the knockout round with a win over Ghana and a draw against Portugal in Group G.
>
> [Source](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/soccer-dirty-tackle/)

Google search shows both "entry ***to***" and "entry ***into***" are used.  But are "entry to" and "entry into" really the same?

Answer (score 2):

Both are okay, but I have read somewhere that there is a subtle difference.

In cases like this, using *entry to* focuses on the fact that you end up in something. On the other hand, *entry into* focuses on the process of entering. It refers to the general meaning of *into*.

Check out the examples:

> My ***entry to*** America is the best thing happened in my life --the focus is on the fact that I entered and ended up in America. The American embassy has rules that define someone's *entry to America.*
>
> The ***entry into*** midtown Manhattan (from Weehawken, NJ) is exciting: the focus is on the process of entering. Lincoln Tunnel is amazing!

Now your case,

As I said, **both are okay**. But IMO, *into* focuses more on the *entrance* and thus *entry into* is what I'd prefer.

It's worth noting that "in" and "into" cannot *always* be interchanged:

> My father is *<del>into</del> in the Indian Air Force

> And I walked right  *<del>in</del>  into* the room and it was all camera and eyes on me.

Comment: A good explanation, but imo the final analysis onwards from "Now your case", for the specific example raised by the OP, is flawed. Personally, I'd remove the discussion of cases of *into* and *in* disassociated from *entry*